# How to turn off Find My iPad without Apple ID password or security questions?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password, find-my-iphone

I have a previously school-owned iPad that I would like to restore but in order to do that I need to turn off 'Find my iPad.' I can't figure out my Apple ID password to do this and I can't reset it because it requires that I use my school email which no longer works and I can't answer the security questions correctly. Is there a way to turn off 'Find my iPad' without an Apple ID password or is there a way to reset my iPad without turning off 'Find my iPad?'

Comment: Is it possible for you to ask the school to remove Activation Lock?(if you restore without disabling Find My iPad, it will just show an Activation Lock screen and will require the Apple ID + password)

Comment: I dont think so, I already graduated

Comment: You need to ask the previous owner to do this. Otherwise how does the system know that it is not stolen?